# Do angular.element returns the actual html code?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-service

I have made a service in angular in that service requires accessing the dom properties of different elements, sample call of the service.

```
panelsService.collectClass(angular.element('.contact-panel-for-same-height'));
```

I did a console log at the service with this code, `console.log('I want to get the offsetHeight of the element', classCollected);`
and tried accessing the `classCollected.offsetHeight` but it returns undefined.
I found out that the `classCollected` is a group of html codes,
and if I forEach `classCollected` i will see the actual html code,
I was expecting to get an object to get the offset height.
How do you access these properties with an html code returned?

[image: Image for reference]

Update: I can get the height using by adding [0] after `classCollected`, code will be `classCollected[0].offsetHeight` but the height that I am getting is not the actual height of my div. It is lesser.

Comment: In my cases I used document.querySelector() to avoid using jQuery

Comment: @Vitalii, what is the difference between document.querySelector() and angular.element()?

Comment: @Vitalii What does this have to do with jQuery?!

Comment: querySelector is a native browser's function. It returns exactly that you want - html element and do this quick and without third party libraries.
angular.element is: 

If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."

Comment: @deceze
How do you access these properties with an html code returned? This is was answer what I am using and reason why I do not use common approach.

Comment: @Vitalii, i tried using `document.querySelector()`, it returns the actual html code, still the same values I received from `angular.element()`, except that angular.element stores the returned values in a **group/array**, while `document.querySelector` only return a **single instace**, it will **discard my previous value** when I call a new one.

Comment: Thank you guys for responding, I already resolved this case, as what I've said above, I can access the height by adding `...[0].offsetHeight` but I receive a smaller height, so i used angulars `$timeout` to delay the execution of the code a bit. It works. It turns out I was receiving the height of the element during its initial stage, or something like that.